# Can Firebase work on Genymotion Emulator?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, genymotion

hi there I just want to know if my android app constructed using firebase for authentication , can only work on physical devices or there is no problem with genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem at all. Just follow this FAQ to install OpenGapps on the device:

https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services

Comment: does Genymotion emulators work on firebase PHONE NUMBER authentication? From https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth it says "Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on an emulator."

Comment: I tested that Android studio's inbuilt emulator can work with Firebase Phone Auth (Testing number only) but Genymotion doesn't work with the same.